# 20.10: Stop windows' edges from resisting crossing other windows' edges

Tags: window, wayland

In Ubuntu 20.10 on Wayland, windows resist having their edges cross eachother whenever their edges align, i.e. when I move a window so that one of its edges overlaps with a parallell edge of another window it won't go past the overlapping edge until I move the cursor a small distance further.

Not only does this happen when their outward edges meet (i.e. a gap between the windows followed by no gap), but it happens **when an inward edge meets an outward edge** as well (overlapping windows move so that their edges align -- windows still overlapping).

Moving a window around is a very jerky experience. I can live with two outward edges resisting overlap, but with inward edges it becomes too much.

**How do I turn this off?**

I could find nothing about window behavior in system settings, and no suitable option in Gnome Tweaks. I couldn't think of a name for this feature to search for.

Comment: `sudo apt install dconf-editor`, launch the app, and use its search feature to explore schemas that are related to the window manager. If there is anything you can do, it probably should be among the settings exposed by dconf-editor.

Comment: @Levente Good idea! I always forget that thing exists. Probably because I could never seem to find anything in there on my own.

Comment: In my experience, the entire schema is not so terribly expansive (on stock Ubuntu 20.04 with gnome, at least). In other words, it's totally worth giving it 20 or so minutes and just manually poke through all the schemas, one after the other; it will give you a good idea of the outline, that will serve you good from then on in any need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed in this [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=679609) opened in 2012, when a request was made to be able to disable this window edge resistance/snapping feature. It is an interesting read.

In Wayland, gnome uses mutter and this has finally been disabled by this [merge request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/1268), which made it into the git master on 14th October 2020. I don't know when you might be able to install this version.

Though a suggestion was made in [February 2019](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/merge_requests/455) to disable the feature and add a toggle option in `dconf`, it was not pursued, to avoid maintenance effort.

Note, you will stilll be able to activate the edge resistance temporarily by using the shift modifier key whist dragging windows.

Comment: That was an interesting read in the sense that it reinforces the OSS reasoning stereotype: 1. We have hardly any market share, 2. No one has been in touch to tell us we're doing something wrong, 3. We're doing things right, guys! After that it's up to users to hit the nail on the head and point out that having to hold down a modifier key for a good experience is "outrageous" and to explain that people's expectations are already so low that the feature will be mistaken for poor performance. Although I agree that the feature *can* be made to work nicely, until it does it should be optional.

Comment: The merge request thread has the right idea. To make it work they only have to make it dependent on pointer speed, and only allow outward edges to collide. Thanks for the links.